# Javascript Object Property Naming

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning javascript from the following book 'JavaScript: The Good Parts - O'Reilly Media', which says the following:

> The quotes around a property’s name in an object literal are optional
>   if the name would be a legal JavaScript name and not a reserved word.
>   So quotes are required around"first-name", but are optional around
>   first_name.

Question: From my research 'first-name' is not a keyword in javascript, so why does the author say quotes are required around it?

Comment: To rephrase the book: the quotes are required if the name is not a legal JavaScript name or if the name is a reserved word.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `first-name`  isn't a valid [**identifier name** as defined by ECMAScript](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.6) :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is going to see that as var first minus var name.

It's not `first-name` thats illegal, it's the us of `-`.